# RMI with Spring and AOP

Tags: java, spring, rmi, spring-aop

I am trying to implement a Spring application with RMI and AOP. I am having problems with my server component. If the service interface which i want to expose does not extend `Remote` and the methods do not throw an `RemoteException`, I am getting the error:

```
UnknownAdviceTypeException: Advice object [org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor@1f90645] is neither a supported subinterface of [org.aopalliance.aop.Advice] nor an [org.springframework.aop.Advisor]
```

if the interface extends `Remote` it works just fine with starting and so on. 
My `application.xml` has only one bean declared:

```
<bean id="testService" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
    <property name="serviceName" value="TestService" />
    <property name="service" ref="testServiceImpl"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface"
        value="xxx.service.TestService" />
</bean>
```

My interface only has the `@Transactional` annotation, while the implementation has the `@Service` annotation.

In my client i get errors as well. Here i get an error of a not unique bean: found bean `testService` and `testServiceImpl`. My client.xml looks like this:

```
<bean class="xxx.start.Client">
    <property name="testService" ref="testService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="testService" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="rmi://localhost:1099/TestService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="xxx.service.TestService"/>
</bean>
```

I followed this [guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html), but go the errors above. If you could help me id be very glad. If i run my JUnit test without RMI, its working all fine

Comment: Don't put `@Transactional` on interfaces this will lead to issues. Put it on your implementation. With this setup you have now you have a proxy of a proxy due to this.

Comment: @M.Deinum but doesn't `@Transactinal` open an Transaction for all methods in the class? if yes it would also open a transaction for methods which don't need one. i tested it with `@Transactional` on the impl and i still get the error about the Advice

Comment: It still does regardless if it is on the interface or not and it will only be applied to methods that are public (which should only be your interface methods).

Comment: in my interface i only have methods which require db access and in my impl also some without (getter and setter(public)). why would it open a transaction for the ones without db access if its on the interface?

Comment: Assuming the getter/setter (which I would say shouldn't be there) are probably called during setup for which a proxy doesn't exists yet and as such doesn't open a tx. Next to that you shouldn't put those annotations on an interface, inheritance of that isn't supported for a reason and Spring uses a workaround for that. If it should be transactional should be an implementation detail not a specification detail.

Comment: getter and setter are there to initialize my DAOs with `@Autowired`. yet i can't find out why i get `UnknownAdviceTypeException` because i even get it in a test project which has no AOP implemented...

Comment: Transactions are AOP and RMI is implemented using proxies just like AOP.

Comment: and do you know how i can fix this?

Comment: I already gave you the solution (based on what you posted here) if that isn't the solution you haven't provided all / enough information.

Comment: i did move the @transactional from the interface to the implementation, but the UnknownAdviceTypeException still occurs. what information would you need?

Comment: the full stack trace would be a start.. And your test.

Comment: i found out why it throws the error. it was because i had default-autowiring set to byType, but the RmiServiceExporter should have autowire=no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out why it throws the error. it was because i had `default-autowiring` set to `byType`, but the `RmiServiceExporter` should have `autowire=no`